# Parted: resize partition without resizing filesystem

Tags: linux, partitioning, filesystems

Can parted resize a partition without resizing the underlying filesystem?

Currently, it prints a warning:

> WARNING: you are attempting to use parted to operate on (resize) a file system. parted's file system manipulation code is not as robust as what you'll find in dedicated, file-system-specific packages like e2fsprogs.  We recommend you use parted only to manipulate partition tables, whenever possible. Support for performing most operations on most types of file systems will be removed in an upcoming release.

Comment: Why would one want to resize the partition but not the filesysem?

Comment: If you would resize the partition but not the filesystem, the filesystem would still believe these sectors are still available for it for free use...to say it with the vocabulary of Dwarf Fortress, that will lead to !!!FUN!!!.

Comment: In my particular case, because parted doesn't resize btrfs yet. But one could, say, want two filesystems in one partition, so the second is somewhat hidden.

Comment: @Bobby Yes, that would occur if you try to shrink the partition without shrinking the filesystem first. If you're looking to expand a partition, the order is reversed.

Answer (score 9):

Resizing a partition is a common task particularly when using hardware RAID, virtual machines etc where disk sized can (and do) change size, even while the OS is running.

Unfortunately, parted will not resize a partition (and never really was able to). To achieve the same thing you must delete the original partition an recreate it with a new end address. You must keep the start address the same or you may corrupt all your data. You must also set any flags back to their original values to ensure that the partition is used correctly at the next boot.

Before starting, make sure you have a backup of you system!

In parted, switch the display unit to sectors with `u s` and print out you current values with `p`

It is worth writing these values down in case you break something and need to restore your original partitions.

Then delete the existing partition `rm`

Then create a new partition with `mkpart`

Finally set the flags with `toggle`

After quiting parted you may need to run `partprobe` to make the kernel update it's view of the partitions eg: `cat /proc/partitions`

When using LVM2, you can make the partition bigger and then run `pvresize /dev/...` and your new capacity will become available to the volume group. You can then proceed with `lvresize` and `resize2fs` or whatever is suited to your OS.

Comment: I wish this would get fixed in parted...

Answer (score -1):

What you're trying to do is risky and difficult at best, and disastrous at worst.

Filesystems are designed to occupy an entire partition by themselves. It is "valid" to have a filesystem that is formatted to occupy less than the entire partition, but it would be very much a hack to try and use the unclaimed space for another filesystem.

There are two types of "resize": grow and shrink.

If your initial state is that one filesystem occupies the entirety of a partition, and you grow the partition (make it larger), that basically means you tweaked the partition table (just a bunch of numbers in a small area of the hard drive, the format depends on your partition type, e.g. MBR or GPT) so that there will be more blocks allocated to the partition than the filesystem is using. The filesystem will not use the additional blocks at the end of the partition, because the filesystem still thinks it's operating on a smaller partition than it actually has. A "smart" filesystem COULD easily detect and start using the remaining space, but I don't know if any actually do that. Either way, you'll probably get at least warnings when mounting your drive.

If you try to shrink the partition (make it smaller) without also shrinking the filesystem, you WILL lose data: when the filesystem tries to write to blocks that are beyond the end of the partition, the device node will throw an exception for trying to write past the boundary of the partition, and the filesystem will throw an I/O error up to userspace. Any data you previously had in the re-partitioned space will be lost.

Either way, you're shooting yourself in the foot. I have no idea how you would even begin to tell a filesystem to mount a filesystem starting at a certain block within a partition. A command like `mount /dev/sda1` implies that the mount starts at the very beginning of the partition. Yes, you would be slightly obscuring the location of any data in the "hidden partition" if you were able to create a filesystem in there; but anyone savvy enough to want to poke around on your hard drive is going to very easily find it, so don't think you're gaining any measure of security.

If you are worried about other users of the computer or unauthorized persons with physical access to the computer, you should use full disk encryption based on strong cryptography. Merely hiding a partition isn't going to confuse most physical-access users for very long if they are looking for interesting things on your disk.

Check out `fdisk` or `cfdisk` if you still want to do this, but you're voiding every warranty in the book (and then some) by doing this...

Comment: As to how to mount a filesystem in the middle of a partition, `mount -o offset` would suffice, I think. Your point about disk encryption is well taken (please note I'm not actually trying to do the two-filesystems-in-one-partition scheme, only trying to resize a btrfs partition). I'm still wondering if parted can do this (as the warning seems to imply), but will look into fdisk and cfdisk, thanks!

Comment: This is a bad answer because There is no other way if one wanted to shrink ext4. Parted will error out when using move or resize  with "Error: File system has an incompatible feature enabled..."